# What is the inverse of an orphan?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

An orphan is a child whose parents have died. Is there a single English word to describe a parent who has lost all their children? If not, what is the most clear and concise description for this condition?

Comment: I don't think there's a single word or standard phrase. "Lost his/her family" might fit, but it kind of implies loss of siblings and spouse.

Answer (score 2):

She/he is called *now childless mother*/ *now childless father*/ *[now childless parent](https://www.facebook.com/NowChildlessParents)*; parents who not only suffered the loss of a child, but who suffered the loss of either their ONLY child or ALL their children.

...And I know how It feels for I once lost a child.